# why does tasks.all works well but tasks.matching not when adding dependencies?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add tests of all flavors to a meta task.
This does not work:

```
subprojects {

 task("testAllFlavors"){
    val buildTask = this
    tasks.matching {
        name.startsWith("test") && name.endsWith("DebugUnitTest")
        }.all {
        buildTask.dependsOn(this)
}
}
```

And this also does not work:

```
subprojects {

 task("testAllFlavors"){
setDependsOn(tasks.matching {
           name.startsWith("test") && name.endsWith("DebugUnitTest")
        })
}
}
```

But this does work:

```
subprojects {
 task("testAllFlavors"){
 val buildTask = this
        tasks.all {
            if(name.startsWith("test") && name.endsWith("DebugUnitTest")) {
                buildTask.dependsOn(this)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

}

What is the difference between the 3 options? The look the same to me? Why does just the third option work ? I use gradle 7.1 and AGP 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the "matching" `this` is not what you think.
It is the `testAllFlavors` task, so you always check the name of that and thus your condition is always `false`.
You would need `it.name...`.
Within the `all` on the other hand, the `this` is the "inner" task which is why your 3rd variant works.

But all your versions have one big drawback, they cause each and every task to be realized, because to check the name in the `matching` or `all`, the task needs to be realized of course, so task-configuration avoidance is prevented.

You should at least match the task by type first to at least limit the tasks that need to be realized to all of that type and then check for their name and you also don't need to use `all`, but can just give the filtered task collection to the `dependsOn`, so something like this:

```
tasks.register("testAllFlavors") {
    dependsOn(tasks.withType<AbstractTestTask>().matching {
        it.name.startsWith("test") && it.name.endsWith("DebugUnitTest")
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was beating my head against the wall, and just saw your note when this also seems to work:
`tasks.matching { it.name.startsWith("publish")}.all {
    dependsOn("release")
}` Any comments on one solution vs the other?

Comment: Not sure which two you are referring to. But anyway what you wrote has the same problem described above. You prevent task configuration avoidance and cause each and every task to be realized. Better in your case if you cannot filter by task type would be `tasks.configureEach { if (name.startsWith("publish")) { dependsOn("release") }` or similar. But without guarantee, writing from the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion works.